# CDF from a probability function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Hi I have this exercise where I must calculate the CDF and I wanted to see if what I have done is correct:
The exercise goes as follows:

Determine the distribution function F of the probability measure $P$ on $(\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R}))$ with the
following density:

$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
&0 & x<m-5\\ 
&\frac{1}{25}(x-m+5) &  m-5 \leq x \leq m\\ 
&-\frac{1}{25}(x-m-5) & m\leq x \leq m+5\\ 
& 0 & m + 5 < x
\end{matrix}\right.$

Then, to calculate the CDF I simply calculated the respective integrals:

$F(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
& F_1(t) & x<m-5\\ 
& F_2(t) &  m-5 \leq x \leq m\\ 
&F_3(t) & m\leq x \leq m+5\\ 
& F_4(t) & m + 5 < x
\end{matrix}\right.$

I know that $F_1(x)=0$ and $F_4(x)=1$

$F_2(t)=\int_{m-5}^{t}\frac{1}{25}(x-m+5)dx=\dfrac{x\cdot\left(x-2m+10\right)}{50}$

$F_3(t)=\int_{m}^{t}\frac{-1}{25}(x-m-5)dx=\dfrac{x-m-5}{25}$

So at the end we have:

$F(x) =
\left\{\begin{matrix}
 &0  &   x<m-5\\ 
 & \dfrac{x\cdot\left(x-2m+10\right)}{50} &  m-5 \leq x \leq m \\ 
 &\dfrac{x-m-5}{25} & m\leq x \leq m+5\\ 
 & 1 & m + 5 < x
\end{matrix}\right.
$

Have I done any errors or is everything allright?

Comment: I haven't checked the calculus, but there is a conceptual mistake. By definition $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt$. Therefore, if a pdf is presented to you in different parts, it is not sufficient to only integrate each part separately. The new part should be added on top of what you had before. In this case, if $m \leq x \leq m+5$ you get $F(x) = F(m) + \int_m^x f(t) dt$.

Comment: Okay so the right answer is $F(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
& F_1(t)=0 & x<m-5\\ 
& F_2(t)=F_1(t)+\int_{m-5}^{t}\frac{1}{25}(x-m+5)dx=\dfrac{x\cdot\left(x-2m+10\right)}{50} &  m-5 m\leq x \leq m\\ 
&F_3(t)=F_2(t)+ \int_{m}^{t}\frac{1}{25}(x-m-5)dx& m\leq x \leq m+5\\ 
& F_4(t)=1 & m + 5 < x
\end{matrix}\right.$

Right?

Comment: $F(x)$ or $F(t)$ ? The condition $m-5\color{red}{m}\le x\le m$ looks wrong. $x(x-2m+10)/50$ is wrong as it is not zero for $x=m-5$.

Comment: Sorry I made a big mess with calculations. So:
$F(x) =
\left\{\begin{matrix}
 &0  &   x<m-5\\ 
 &F_2(t)=F_1(t)+\int_{m-5}^t\frac{1}{25}(x-m+5)dx=\dfrac{t^2+\left(10-2m\right)t+m^2-10m+25}{50} &  m-5 \leq x \leq m \\ 
 &F_3(t)=F_2(t)+\int_{m}^t\frac{1}{25}(x-m-5)dx & m\leq x \leq m+5\\ 
 & 1 & m + 5 < x
\end{matrix}\right.
$

Comment: and in the conditions I must write a t instead of x

Comment: Yes, indeed, because $t$ is your variable. Also, in the expression for $F_3(t)$, it should be $F_2(m)$ instead of $F_2(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extending a little bit the suggestion from @Rik93, using your notation and indicator functions:
$$F(x)=\mathbf{1}_{(m-5\le x \le m)}(x)F_2(x)+\mathbf{1}_{(m< x \le m+5)}(x)[F_2(m)+F_3(x)]+\mathbf{1}_{(m+5<x)}(x)$$